# Interrogating Core Data one-to-one relationship

Tags: core-data, relationship, predicate

hopefully, this is a simple question, but I cant find the answer in core data docs. I have an app setting up employees as members of functions (departments) using the relationship isfuncmember<<->funcmembers. That's all fine. I also have the ability to set one of these employees as a function manager using functionmanager<-->hasmanager. I have a view to set up the employee with a switch to turn on their status as function manager. I also have an editing view to edit employee details, which I want to open in ViewDidLoad with the Function manager switch set to the current value. How do I interrogate whether functionmanager<-->hasmanager has been set for that employee? I've tried this but it results in an lldb crash with no error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Setting the value of fields in this table to that of the passed StaffMember");
    self.surname.text = self.person.surname;
    self.firstname.text = self.person.firstname;

    self.telwork.text = self.person.telwork;
    self.telhome.text = self.person.telmob;
    self.email.text = self.person.email;
    self.function.text = self.person.isfuncmember.name;
    self.selectedFunction = self.person.isfuncmember;
    if([self.person.functionmanager.name isEqual:self.person.isfuncmember.name]) {
        // functionmanager selected on
        [isfuncman setOn:YES];
    }

    else {
        // functionmanager selected off
        [isfuncman setOn:NO];
    }

    if([self.person.linemanager isEqual: @"YES"]) {
        // linemanager selected on
        [islineman setOn:YES];
    }

    else {
        // functionmanager selected off
        [islineman setOn:NO];
    }


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Here's the slice of the data model. 
[image: Datal model slice]

Comment: You need to improve your naming. is... and has... would be expected to return a BOOL, not an object. Also, if the relationships are bi-directional (they should be) then just check if the employee has a function. A picture of the data model would really help too.

Comment: Thanks Wain - I've added the data model. Is the comment on naming just sloppy practice I need to clean up, which doesn't affect the current code, or have I also introduced errors? As to the employee, they already have an established function relationship, I want to find out if they also have an established relationship with the function using the function manager<->hasmanager. What I need is the code for checking the status of the latter relationship - i.e. has it been set for that particular employee?

Comment: The naming is just misleading. It shouldn't actually be causing a problem. Can you not just do 'if ([function.hasmanager isEqual:staffMember]) {...' where staffMember is the employee and function is the function you're testing.

Comment: Thanks Wain - worked perfectly. Sometimes, if you're looking down one end of the telescope, you forget to think about using the view from the other end!